# Compact subsets of $M(n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: metric-spaces

Consider $M(n,\mathbb R)$, the space of all  $ n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb R$.Which of the following are compact?
a.$O(n)$ the set of all orthogonal matrices

b.$GL(n,\mathbb R)$ set of all non-singular matrices over $\mathbb R$

c.$SL(n,\mathbb R)$ set of all non-singular matrices over $\mathbb R$ with determinant equals one.

d.set of all nilpotent matrices.

Answer:since the determinant map is continuous and continuous image of a compact set is compact using them I have concluded (b) is not compact since image set  of (b) is $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$. Is  it correct?But how to approach the others ?

Comment: If you are using the usual topology, then a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: Hi, I made an edit on (c), I hope that is what you mean

Comment: Ya its true thanks @John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show that the spaces mentionned in b), c) and d) are not compact, it is sufficient to exhib an unbounded sequence in these spaces. For example, consider respectively $$\left( \begin{matrix} n & 0 \\ 0 & n \end{matrix} \right), \ \left( \begin{matrix} n+1 & 1 \\ n & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \ \text{and} \ \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & n \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right).$$

Afterwards, you can show that $O(n)$ is compact by proving that it is closed and bounded.

**Hint:** if $M \in O(n)$, notice that $\|M\| \leq 1$ where $\|M\| : = \sup\limits_{ \| x \| =1 } \|Mx\|$.

Comment: How does the fourth matrix be a nilpotent one?

Comment: Sorry, I read *idempotent* instead of *nilpotent*. I edited my answer, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Or $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1/n&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is a sequence of invertible matrices converging to a noninvertible one.

Comment: I am taking norm of a matrix M as$||M||:=(\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}^2|)^{1/2}$ So I am not getting the Hint @Seirios

Comment: The choice of the norm does not matter: they are all equivalent.